# How do I benefit from argc and argv in C++, the standard way?

Tags: c++, linux, argv, argc

What is the standard way to retrive and check for the argc and argv and what is the best usage and how to do that in linux?

Please provide examples.

"I want to have a complex command-line options and I want to use them in my application"
That what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "check for?"  Either you have `int main()` or you have `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`.  If you have the former, you don't have the argument vector, if you have the latter you do.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A bunch of simple arguments? Complex command-line options?

Comment: Extremely unclear question. You don't have to retrieve argc/argv -- they're passed to you as arguments to `main()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use boost program options http://www.boost.org/doc/html/program_options.html for access to the command arguments.

Comment: +1 for showing OP where to buy a wheel rather than build one.

Answer (score 8):

There are (at least) two ways to write your `main` function:

```
int main()
{
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
}
```

If you use the second option, then your command line arguments will be in `argv`, which has `argc` # of elements:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "arg #" << i << ": " << argv[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing the array syntax, when so many just "char **argv". i know it's the same

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> arguments(argv, arv+argc);`

Answer (score 4):

What do you want to do with them?

A simple example of usage is like the following:

```
// Get numbers from the command line, and put them in a vector.
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* get the numbers from the command line. For example:

           $ my_prog 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    */
    std::vector<int> numbers(argc-1);
    try
    {
        std::transform(argv+1, argv+argc, numbers.begin(),
                       boost::lexical_cast<int, char*>);
    }
    catch(const std::exception&)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: You have entered invalid numbers.";
    }
}
```

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you have many types of arguments etc.. Then it is better to use something like [`boost program options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

Works in both C and C++, though in C++ you should include cstdio and in C you should include stdio.h.

Comment: As opposed to correctly answering the actual question? I'm no C++ expert, so excuse my ignorance, but what's so horrendous about `printf`?

Comment: If the question had been tagged as C then printf would be OK. But this question is tagged C++ so you should be using the type safe mechanism provided to you be the language not relying on backward compatibility with another language.